# How do I completely wipe all TFS mappings from my machine?

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Over the past few years, I have ended up with multiple projects mapped all over my hard disk haphazardly from VS 2008,2010,2012,2013

Is there an easy way to unmap (and delete local files of) all TFS projects mapped on my machine? After that I'll map them manually as and when I need to

Comment: for 2005-2010, look at the `tf workspace` command. I believe that `tf workspace /owner:YourUserName /remove:*` will do it, but check the documentation for each version, and be sure to execute it with the Visual Studio command prompt. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3%28VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Go to Visual Studio Command Prompt. Type tf workspace and click Enter. You will get all the mapping. you can remove all if you want. Thanks